# Handle concurrent requests to update the resources

Tags: concurrency, distributed-system, high-traffic

In an interview i have been asked the below question.

> In an inventory we have the quantity for an item is 2.
>
> There are two concurrent requests to our distributed system
>
> - 1st request went to server1
> - 2nd request went to server2
>
> Now we need to gracefully handle the use case by serving any one request successfully other with no stock available.
>
> Conditions:
> We should not use table level locks to achieve this.

Kindly help me how can we achieve this.

Comment: If the quantity is 2, why wouldn't both requests succeed?